# Instantiate Sencha Touch Controller in the HTML file

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I instantiate the Sencha Touch controller inside my HTML file?

I have a reference to the controller JS file as shown below:

```
  <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/app/controller/MyController.js"></script>
```

I try to create an instance like this:

```
var controller = Ext.create('MyController'); // this does not create an instance
controller.doSomething();  // doSomething is never called!
```

But the app stucks at the above line and does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you won't be able to do this is because Sencha Touch isn't loaded immediately and takes time to initialise.

You could fire an event in the app's launch method, and listen to this from HTML.

That said, it's fairly horrible in terms of best practices, so perhaps there's another way of achieving what you need. Be happy to try to advise if you let us know what the use case is.